# Bold words in a string of json file in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have a long text in one of the strings at json file. I want to make bold of some words in that text.

How can I do it?

sample.json file:

```
    {
        "local_id": "82",
        "local_title": "He is Lord",
        "local_hint": "He is Lord",
        "local_text": "He is Lord, He is Lord\nHe is risen from the dead and He is Lord\nEvery knee shall bow,\nevery tongue confess\nThat Jesus Christ is Lord.",
        "local_category": "nothing",
        "local_categorycount": "1"


    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with making bold of some words? What words? How is the text displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON only stores plain text, It does not format the text, if you want to make the data in the JSON object appear bold or colorful in the UI you need to handle this from the front end side.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Accepted your comment